# How to implement ChimpKit3?

Tags: objective-c

I'm having big difficulties following the example in the ChimpKit readme on [github](https://github.com/mailchimp/ChimpKit3).

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"id": @"8ce4588803", @"email": @{@"email": @"foo@example.com"}, @"merge_vars": @{@"FNAME": @"Freddie", @"LName":@"von Chimpenheimer"}};
    [[ChimpKit sharedKit] callApiMethod:@"lists/subscribe" withParams:params andCompletionHandler:^(ChimpKitRequest *request, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"HTTP Status Code: %d", request.response.statusCode);
        NSLog(@"Response String: %@", request.responseString);

        if (error) {
            //Handle connection error
            NSLog(@"Error, %@", error);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //Update UI here
            });
        } else {
            NSError *parseError = nil;
            id response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:request.responseData
                                                          options:0
                                                            error:&parseError];
            if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                id email = [response objectForKey:@"email"];
                if ([email isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                    //Successfully subscribed email address
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        //Update UI here
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }];
```

Apparently this is the code to subscribe an email to a list in MailChimp

I am getting errors:

> /SubscribeEmailViewController.m:146:105: Expected ')'
>
> SubscribeEmailViewController.m:146:103: Type specifier missing,
>   defaults to 'int'
>
> SubscribebeEmailViewController.m:147:44: Use of undeclared identifier
>   'request'
>
> SubscribeEmailViewController.m:146:103: Incompatible block pointer
>   types sending 'int ((^)(void))' to parameter of type
>   'ChimpKitRequestCompletionBlock' (aka 'void (^)(NSURLResponse
>   *__strong, NSData *__strong, NSError *__strong)')

This is basically copy and paste from the example, I can't figure out what detail I'm missing here. 
ChimpKit was installed via cocoapods

Comment: Which line is line 146?

Comment: [[ChimpKit sharedKit] callApiMethod:@"lists/subscribe" withParams:params andCompletionHandler:^(ChimpKitRequest *request, NSError *error) {